# Animating an SVG pattern background

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, next.js

I'm currently designing a new website with NextJS and Tailwind and I would like to make a background that is infinitely translating to the bottom right, just like in this example (but with my own pattern):

https://codepen.io/kootoopas/pen/reyqg

I've actually never worked with SVG patterns before. Though I've managed to display an SVG pattern as follows, I can't seem to find how to animate it.

The SVG is displayed in a flexbox div like so:

```html
<div className="opacity-50 absolute inset-0 scale-150">
   <svg width="100%" height="100%">
      <defs>
         <pattern id="p" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path id="a" data-color="fill" fill="#FFF" d="M0 50v50h50C22.386 100 0 77.614 0 50zM100 50C72.386 50 50 27.614 50 0v50h50zM50 25V0C22.386 0 0 22.386 0 50h25c0-13.807 11.193-25 25-25zM100 75V50c-27.614 0-50 22.386-50 50h25c0-13.807 11.193-25 25-25zM25 50c0 13.807 11.193 25 25 25V50H25zM75 0c0 13.807 11.193 25 25 25V0H75z"></path>
</pattern>
      </defs>
      <rect fill="#EEB400" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      <rect fill="url(#p)" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
   </svg>
</div>
```

I've tried to apply CSS classes, custom React components on it, with no avail.

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: one solution would be animating the x and y attributes of the pattern from 0 to 100 with SMIL : `<animate attributeName="x" from="0" to="100" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />` and the same for y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="p" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path data-color="fill" fill="#FFF" d="M0 50v50h50C22.386 100 0 77.614 0 50zM100 50C72.386 50 50 27.614 50 0v50h50zM50 25V0C22.386 0 0 22.386 0 50h25c0-13.807 11.193-25 25-25zM100 75V50c-27.614 0-50 22.386-50 50h25c0-13.807 11.193-25 25-25zM25 50c0 13.807 11.193 25 25 25V50H25zM75 0c0 13.807 11.193 25 25 25V0H75z"></path>
            <animateTransform attributeName="patternTransform" type="translate" by="100 100" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="#EEB400" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
    <rect fill="url(#p)" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
</svg>
```